# WSO2 CEP On-demand query and continuous queries

Tags: wso2, esper, wso2-cep

I am currently using **Esper CEP** and wondering whether I can replace it with the **WSO2 CEP**. Trying do to a feature comparison of the two. The very first question based on my use case is -

Does **WSO2 CEP** support on-demand queries and continuous queries like **Esper**?

If yes, how? Do we have some examples or documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes CEP supports continuous queries with query language called Siddhi. 
Can you please mention use cases and examples for on-demand queries you are expecting from WSO2 CEP?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Complex Event Processor (WSO2 CEP) helps identify the most meaningful events and patterns from multiple data sources, analyze their impacts, and act on them in real time.

Hope these links will help you get some insights on WSO2 CEP.

1. http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/
2. http://wso2.com/library/articles/cep/
3. http://srinathsview.blogspot.com/2014/07/handling-large-scale-cep-usecase-with.html
4. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/08/wso2-cep-in-action-an-analysis-of-use-in-real-world-applications-of-different-domains/

Please share us exact use case which you are to trying out?